# Pyspark remove duplicate columns in a dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I found many solutions are related with `join` situation. My question is if the duplicates exist in the dataframe itself, how to detect and remove them? The following example is just showing how I create a data frame with duplicate columns.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
(1, "A", "X1"),
(2, "B", "X2"),
(3, "B", "X3"),
], ["ID", "TYPE", "CODE"])

df1 = df.withColumn("TYPE1", df["TYPE"]).withColumn("TYPE2", df["TYPE"])

+---+----+----+
| ID|TYPE|CODE|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   A|  X1|
|  2|   B|  X2|
|  3|   B|  X3|
+---+----+----+

+---+----+----+-----+-----+
| ID|TYPE|CODE|TYPE1|TYPE2|
+---+----+----+-----+-----+
|  1|   A|  X1|    A|    A|
|  2|   B|  X2|    B|    B|
|  3|   B|  X3|    B|    B|
+---+----+----+-----+-----+
```

Suppose I am just given `df1`, how can I remove duplicate columns to get `df`? Thanks!

Comment: if you have df1 how do you know to keep TYPE column and drop TYPE1 and TYPE2?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I will compare between different columns to see whether they are the same. If so, then I just keep one column and drop the other one. I don't care about the column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop the duplicate columns by comparing all unique permutations of columns that potentially be identical. You can use the `itertools` library and `combinations` to calculate these unique permutations:

```
from itertools import combinations
#select columns that can be identical, can also be a hardcoded list
L = filter(lambda x: 'TYPE' in x,df1.columns) 
#we only want to do pairwise comparisons, so the second value of combinations is 2
permutations = [(map(str, comb)) for comb in combinations(L, 2)]
```

For each of these unique permutations, you can then they are completely identical using a `filter` statement in combination with a `count`.

```
columns_to_drop = set()
for permutation in permutations:
    if df1.filter(df1[permutation[0]] != df1[permutation[1]]).count()==0:
        columns_to_drop.add(permutation[1])
```

This will give you a list of columns to drop. You can then use the following list comprehension to drop these duplicate columns.

```
df.select([c for c in df.columns if c not in columns_to_drop]).show()
```

For your example, this gives the following output:

```
+---+----+----+
| ID|TYPE|CODE|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   A|  X1|
|  2|   B|  X2|
|  3|   B|  X3|
+---+----+----+
```

Comment: `df.select(name1, name2).filter(df[name1] == df[name2]).count() == df.count()` is better