# How to remove column duplication in PySpark DataFrame without declare column name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Here's what I did in pandas

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

How to do this in PySpark?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230666/pyspark-remove-duplicate-columns-in-a-dataframe), but the amount of code is too different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a similar problem, I have been using the below function to drop duplicated columns in a dataframe and return a new one.

Note that this function keeps the first occurrence of the duplicated column:

```
def drop_dup_cols(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    """
    The function returns a DataFrame with unique columns, keeping first occurence 
    :param df: a Spark DataFrame with the duplicated columns
    :returns: a Spark DataFrame, with unique columns
    """
    # Create empty lists to insert duplicated or unique columns   
    newcols = []
    dupcols = []

    # Loop through the columns of the DF and append the lists above
    [newcols.append(df.columns[i]) if df.columns[i] not in newcols else dupcols.append(df.columns[i]) for i in range(len(df.columns))]
    
    # Update your DF
    df = df.toDF(*[str(i) for i in range(len(df.columns))])
    for dupcol in dupcols:
        df = df.drop(str(dupcol))

    return df.toDF(*newcols)
```

It takes a `DF` and returns the same without the duplicated columns.

- To demonstrate (using @werner sample DF):

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6]], schema=["A","B","B","C","C","C"])

>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  B|  C|  C|  C|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+

>>> drop_dup_cols(df).show()
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  4|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the column names unique and then create a new dataframe with unique columns:

```python
df=spark.createDataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6]], schema=["A","B","B","C","C","C"])
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#|  A|  B|  B|  C|  C|  C|
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+

result=list()
for c in df.columns:
    while c in result:
        c = c + "_" 
    result.append(c)
#result = ['A', 'B', 'B_', 'C', 'C_', 'C__']

df_unique=spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, result) \
    .select(*set(df.columns))
#+---+---+---+
#|  A|  C|  B|
#+---+---+---+
#|  1|  4|  2|
#+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to select required columns manually or you have to go with new column. This is beacause spark dataframes are immutable.

Comment: Can you give example code with simulated dataframe?

Comment: I'm assuming you have two different columns with same data. Is my understanding correct ?